# Flexbox div not showing in Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, flexbox

Im trying to set up a simple html layout with a header, a sidebar and a big div for a map. For some reason i see the desired behavior when using Mozilla Firefox, but not in Google Chrome.

So far I have found no answer.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hporaozk/4/

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">HEADER</div>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="sidebar">
            <p>item</p>
            <p>item</p>
            <p>item</p>
            <p>item</p>
            <p>item</p>
            <p>item</p>
            <p>item</p>
            <p>item</p>
            <p>item</p>
            <p>item</p>
            <p>item</p>
            <p>item</p>
            <p>item</p>
            <p>item</p>
            <p>item</p>
            <p>item</p>
        </div>
        <div class="map-container">
            <div class="map">actual map</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.wrapper{
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.header{
    flex: 0 0 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ff0000;
}

.content{
    flex: 1;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.sidebar{   
    background-color: #00ff00;
    flex: 0 0 240px;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.map-container{
    flex: 1;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.map{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #0000ff;
}
```

Chrome: [image: Chrome Screenshot]
Firefox:[image: Firefox Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go: [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/t6pwwgxL/20/)

The most important part is to set your flex items (`.map-container` and `.sidebar`) to `flex-basis: 50%` which is in the flex shorthand `flex: 0 1 50%`

You can adjust those accordingly.

### CSS

```
.wrapper {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
}
.header {
    flex: 0 0 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
.content {
    flex: 1 0 100%;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
    justify-content: space-around;
    -webkit-align-content: flex-start;
    align-content: flex-start;
    -webkit-align-items: space-around;
    align-items: space-around;
}
.sidebar {
    background-color: #00ff00;
    -webkit-flex: 0 1 50%;
    flex: 0 1 50%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
.map-container {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-flex: 0 1 50%;
    flex: 0 1 50%;
}
.map {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #0000ff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I hope you always use prefixes if you're working with flex-box, otherwise you will have a lot of funky business to work with.

In this case you problem is easy to solve:

Just set a height on .content!

```css
.content{
    flex: 1;
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    height: 100%; // add this
}
```

Comment: Currently the only prefix you need to use is `-webkit` for Safari. http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox